# Custom CSS not working for IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I've created a custom CSS for IE8. While the ie8 custom CSS file renders fine in the Internet Explorer emulator (F12) it doesn't actually work on VirtualBox or a laptop I have running a copy of IE8.

Anyone know why the custom CSS fails to render on an actual copy of IE8?

The site is silver cross dot com.

Comment: Why bother? http://gs.statcounter.com/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Instead of creating a separate CSS file (ie8.css), instead use the following syntax \0/ to distinguish only IE8 entries in your main CSS file like so

```
.classname { font-size:15px; }
```

For IE8 Only:

```
.classname { font-size:15px\0/; }
```